# Teradada function Oreplace, what is the similar of this function?

Tags: teradata

I am using Oreplace function in a query, but when i use the function more than 6 times have overflow size error, any solution for this ? other funtction maby. thanks.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and your expected results after all of this oreplacing? I suspect a well designed `regexp_replace()` or similar would be more performant.

Comment: The default type returned by oTranslate is a VarChar(8000), simply cast it to an appropriate size.

Comment: I am casting 18 columns, with an extention of 15 chars, and after 8 columns, have the error.

Comment: 8*8000= 64000, a bit less than the max rowsize in Teradata. `cast(oReplace(...) as varchar(15))`

Comment: Thanks for the information, but teradata show the error.

Comment: Can you show the actual SQL?

Comment: Which TD version? Built-in or custom oreplace? Need to see code and preferably table DDL.